# Не работает атрибут "download"

Tags: html, download

Строка

```html
<a href="images/kkk.jpg" download="Kkk.jpg>Download this file!</a>
```

Перекидывает меня на страничку с изображение и даже не собирается его скачивать. В чём проблема? Браузер Chrome (75v).

---

**UPD** Картинка лежит на компьютере, сайт ещё не выгружен.

Comment: Это значит что ваш вопрос уже задавали. Нет смысла задать опять. Заходите по ссылке сверху и там найдёте ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Я знаю, что это означает. Но там немного по другому. Мне нужно с нуля.

Comment: и что же значит с нуля ? сайт с нуля написать ? картинку на страницу добавить ?

Comment: Да даже проблема не в этом. Как сделать это без создания переменной, добавления элемента на страницу? Там о стриме, фото по клику. А у меня другое. Так трудно написать ответ?

Comment: опишите тогда вопрос детально ибо в том виде в каком он есть, его закроют как дубликат и все.

Comment: а что тут детальнее описывать? Скачать определённое изображение по клику на кнопку. Изображение находится в папке images, кнопка вроде как на сайте. Достаточно?

Comment: тоесть картинка лежит на сервере ? ну и уточнеия к вопросу желательно писать в вопрос, там есть кнопка "править"

Comment: картинка лежит на компьютере, сайт ещё не выгружен.

Comment: `<a href="images/kkk.jpg" download>Download this file!</a>` может быть так ?

Comment: на это действие накладываются ограничения https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872902/chrome-download-attribute-not-working

Comment: Попробуйте все таки выгрузить сайт и картинки. А там, если опять не поможет, можно .htaccess попробовать покрутить:
Options -Indexes
ForceType application/octet-stream

Comment: Я когда то тоже отлаживал сайты локально на компе с Виндой. CGI-сервачек стоял, Апач... Потом надоело, все таки Майкрософт и Юникс это в корне разные вещи )
А сейчас, тем более, когда времена диалапа прошли, зачем локально то? Поставьте например WinSCP - она умеет поддерживать FTP соединение. И делайте всё на хостере! Создайте поддомен test там я не знаю. Делов то. А то, локально всё отладил наконец за 100500 часов, радостный выгружаешь - и .. тебе!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас в коде отсутствует одна кавычка вот эта после `JPG` 
`jpg">Download this file!</a>`

Comment: _совпадать вплоть до регистра_ - это не так, они могут быть разными.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Спасибо за замечание, сейчас исправлю ответ

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, Ваша проблема в том, что Вы проделываете это локально.

Я тоже однажды столкнулся с этим.

Артибут "download" работает, если на сервере запускать (локальном или на хостинге).